# How to detect VK_ESCAPE key press in a Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

When I run this thread, the VK_ESCAPE key is not detected, but if similar code is executed in the main thread the key is detected.  How do you detect a key press in a thread?

```
type

  { A TThread descendent for Saving Pictures }
  TFileSavingThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure ImageEnProcFinishWork(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImageEnProcProgress(Sender: TObject; per: integer);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
  end;

Form1.KeyPreview = true;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_ESCAPE then
    ACancel := True;
end;

procedure TFileSavingThread.Execute;
var
  iImageEnIO: TImageEnIO;
  iFolder: string;
  iFilename: string;
  iNode: TTreeNode;
begin

  inherited;

  { Get the Folder }
  if not Terminated then
  begin
    Synchronize(
      procedure
      begin
        iFolder := Form1.Folder1.Text;
      end);
  end;

  iImageEnIO := TImageEnIO.Create(nil);
  try

    iImageEnIO.OnProgress := ImageEnProcProgress;
    iImageEnIO.OnFinishWork := ImageEnProcFinishWork;

     { Save the Pictures }
    if not Terminated then
    begin
      Synchronize(
        procedure
        var
          i: integer;
        begin
          for i := 1 to Form1.TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do
          begin
            Form1.LabelProgress1.Caption := 'Saving image ' + IntToStr(i) +
              ' of ' + IntToStr(Form1.TreeView1.Items.Count) +
              ' Press ESC to cancel.';
            Form1.LabelProgress1.Update;
            { Get the image from the camera }
            iNode := Form1.TreeView1.Items[i];
            iImageEnIO.WIAParams.ProcessingBitmap := iImageEnIO.IEBitmap;
            iImageEnIO.WIAParams.Transfer(TIEWiaItem(iNode.Data), False);
            { Get the filename }
            iFilename := iNode.Text + '.jpg';
            iImageEnIO.SaveToFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(iFolder) +
              iFilename);
            if Form1.ACancel then
              Terminate;
          end;
        end);
    end;

  finally
    iImageEnIO.Free;
  end;

end;
```

**Edit**

I understand that to properly write this thread, the time consuming part of this should be in the thread itself and not in Syncronize.  The real problem is how to put this code in the thread outside of the Syncronize loop?

```
 iImageEnIO.WIAParams.ProcessingBitmap := iImageEnIO.IEBitmap;
 iImageEnIO.WIAParams.Transfer(TIEWiaItem(iNode.Data), False);
 { Get the filename }
 iFilename := iNode.Text + '.jpg';
 iImageEnIO.SaveToFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(iFolder) + iFilename);
```

Maybe store the images in an array of TBitmap then access the bitmaps in a loop in the thread to save the bitmaps to disk?

I think what I need to do is to get the folder, the filename and the bitmap in Syncronize but save the bitmap in the thread itself.  I just can not see how to do this because there is a loop to get the images and a call to save the image to disk also needs to be in the loop?

Comment: When you do all your work within Synchronize, you are not really executing within the background thread. Try adding an Application.ProcessMessages; call to your loop.

Comment: @500 the analysis is accurate but your suggested cure is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the code on the UI thread. That's what `Synchronize` does. Because of that, because the UI thread is busy, it is not able to pump the message queue. And so your queued input events do not get processed.

Essentially your thread is coded incorrectly. Since all the work is synchronised onto the UI thread, your use of the thread gives you complexity without benefit.

If you want to put long running tasks onto a background thread then you need to execute the work on that thread. You need to do all the time consuming work on the background thread, but put only the UI progress updating onto the main thread.

You do this by running the loop and the processing of the image on the thread.   Only when you want to show UI do you use `Synchronize`.

---

Your `ACancel` variable is badly named. Use that prefix for a parameter. This is a field and should be `FCancel`.

That said, the field is rather pointless. You should remove it and use the built-in termination mechanism. Call `Terminate` on the thread. Inside the thread `Execute` method it makes no sense to call `Terminate` as you do. When you need to quit, just exit the method. And you know when to quit because the `Terminated` property is `True`.

Comment: Yes, the thread is not any faster then when I don't use a thread.  I understand what you are saying, but because the images are obtained in a loop, I do not see how to code the iImageEnIO.SaveToFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(iFolder) +
 iFilename);.. the time consuming work in the thread without it being in the Syncronize loop.  Any suggestions, or the may be an instance where the processing just should not be done in a thread.

Comment: Remember that I have no idea what your long running code is. Why do you feel that the long running code must run in the main thread?

Comment: The time consuming code is saving the image.  See my edited question.  How to save the image in the thread and not in Syncronize?

Comment: Simple. Keep the time-consuming part of the thread method outside any calls to `Synchronize`.

Comment: By the way, your edit changes the question. The first question asks why the keyboard event was not processed. The second question asks how to implement the solution to the first question. When we do that, will there be a third question asking how to debug the second question? And so on.

Comment: I understand. but my question changed after I saw your response.

Comment: Indeed! That's what I just said. It is unfair to change the question. I answered the question that you asked. I spent time and effort doing so. You must appreciate the difference between solving your problem, and answering the question that you asked. I'm writing another answer for your second question. But it really should be a new question.

Comment: David... can we chat somehow?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47094/discussion-between-david-heffernan-and-bill)

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a second answer to address your second question. Really these should be two separate questions. You have the following scenario:

1. You need to read from a GUI control to obtain the filenames and data specification for the image processing. This needs to run on the UI thread because it accesses state held in the GUI.
2. You want to use a thread to perform the saving because it is time consuming, and you don't want to block the UI.

What you need to do to solve this is to de-couple the gathering of the information needed to perform the tasks, from the actual performing of those tasks. So structure the code like this:

```
type
  TTask = record
    FileName: string;
    // other information specifying task
  end;

procedure TMyForm.SaveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Tasks: TArray<TTask>;
begin
  SetLength(Tasks, TreeView1.Items.Count);
  for i := 0 to high(Tasks) do
    Tasks[i] := GetTask(i);//you need to write GetTask
  end;
  FSaveThread := TSaveThread.Create(Tasks);
end;
```

Your thread might look like this:

```
type
  TSaveThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTasks: TArray<TTask>;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const Tasks: TArray<TTask>);
  end;

constructor TSaveThread.Create(const Tasks: TArray<TTask>);
begin 
  inherited Create(False);
  FTasks := Tasks;
end;

procedure TSaveThread.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(FTasks) do
  begin
    if Terminated then
      exit;
    ProcessTask(FTasks[i]);//again, you need to write this
    Sychronize(UpdateUI);
  end;
end;
```

The point being that you gather the information needed to perform the operation up-front. This involves accessing the UI and can take place in the event handler, or a method called from it. Then once all the information is gathered, it is passed to the thread which can concentrate on doing the work without worrying about further access of the GUI. Yes you'll want to do progress reporting, but that is quick and easy and can be readily done without blocking the UI.